# Join performance: Oracle vs MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, oracle

Given a query reduced to the form:

```
select b.field1
from table_a a
    inner join table_b b on b.field1 = a.field1
    left join table_c c on c.field1 = a.field1
    left join table_d d on d.field1 = b.field1
    left join table_e e on e.field1 = b.field6
group by b.field1,
         b.field2,
         b.field3,
         b.field4,
         b.field5,

         e.field2,
         e.field3
;
```

With a certain amount of data it is running in 20 seconds in Oracle. Nothing is indexed in Oracle.
Migrated into MySQL the query does not want to finish (executes in minutes). Every field in question is indexed in MySQL. `Explain` tells that everything is fine.

After still not working, the grouping fields got multiple-column indexes. Still nothing.

What can be the problem that there is still a huge leak in the MySQL performance? Is there a method to speed it up?

Comment: Could you also confirm that the infrastructure is the same in both tests?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. Also, I put the field in the select, because otherwise it threw an error in Oracle (Pl/SQL). Just wanted to reduce the query as much as I could.

Comment: my friend not all the performance go with the index, also go the engine, cache, buffer, etc....

Comment: did you analyze your table after loading it?

Comment: What do you mean analyze and loading?

Comment: Did you get explain plan for your query?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I meant explain. I edited the question. Yes, explain showed everything is indexed.

Comment: I meant this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html

Comment: please paste the result of show profile: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html

Answer (score 8):

`Oracle` is able to do hash joins and merge joins, `MySQL` is not.

Since your tables are not filtered in any way, hash joins would be the most efficient way to do the joins, especially if you don't have any indexes.

With nested loops, even if all join fields are indexed, `MySQL` needs to do an index seek on each value from the leading table in a loop (each time starting from the root index page), then do the table lookup to retrieve the record, then repeat it for each joined table. This involves lots of random seeks.

A hash join, on the other side, requires scanning the smaller table once (building a hash table) then scanning the bigger table once (searching the hash table built). This involves sequential scans which are much faster.

Also, with nested loops, a left-joined table can only be driven (scanned in the inner loop), while with a hash join tables on either side can be leading (scanned) or driven (hashed then searched). This affects performance too.

`MySQL`'s optimizer, though does support a couple of handy tricks which other engines lack, has very limited capabilities compared to other engines and currently supports neither hash joins nor merge joins. Thus said, a query like this would most probably be slow on `MySQL`, even if it's fast on other engines on the same data.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve that with MySQL?

Comment: @user1433877: achieve what, hash joins? No.

Comment: +1 But other than the hash tables could there a way to make a workaround?

Comment: @user1433877: MySQL is only capable of nested loops. There are many things which cannot be implemented efficiently in MySQL, your query is one of them

Comment: @user1433877: Try PostgreSQL, it can handle queries like this, it does have hash joins and merge joins. When you're familiar with Oracle, you will feel comfortable with PostgreSQL quickly.

Comment: Its seems some sort of hash-like join algorithms are been implemented recently, but it does not mention which version. But sure hash join its been implemented into the MariaDB fork https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/05/31/a-case-for-mariadbs-hash-joins/